# Generating random integer numpy vector with a fixed sum

Tags: python, numpy

Based on the codes, i want to randomize the integer where there are specific range specify but in the last three array I need to have `100` in total. The sum of the last three array cannot be exceed than `100`. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
self.position = np.array([rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,2), rd.randint(0,100), rd.randint(0,50), rd.randint(0,1)])
```

Comment: What do you mean in "last three array"? The last three values of the array?

Comment: Do you want to create an array where the sum of the last three elements is 100?

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution **Rmano** suggest is valid, it lack total randomness because once you draw the first random integer the other are pseudo-random or not random at all because of the dependent.

A more random solution would be, in  my opinion:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_fix_sum_random_vec(limit, num_elem, tries=10):
    v = np.random.randint(0, limit, num_elem)
    s = sum(v)
    if (np.sum(np.round(v/s*limit)) == limit):
        return np.round(v / s * limit)
    elif (np.sum(np.floor(v/s*limit)) == limit):
        return np.floor(v / s * limit)
    elif (np.sum(np.ceil(v/s*limit)) == limit):
        return np.ceil(v / s * limit)
    else:
        return generate_fix_sum_random_vec(limit, num_elem, tries-1)



for i in range(25):
    test_vec = generate_fix_sum_random_vec(100, 3)
    test_vec = test_vec.astype(int)
    print("vec: ", test_vec, "sum of vector: ", np.sum(test_vec))
```

This solution is more robust, and can be valid to any limit on the sum of the vector and it easily applicable to vector in any length by changing the `num_elem`. Moreover it doesn't assume anything and just trying until it find a match.

The output of the loop:

```
vec:  [53 32 15] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [40 38 22] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [56 38  6] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [ 5 17 78] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [12 29 59] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [ 1 34 65] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [ 3 56 41] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [35 65  0] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [54  9 37] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [45  8 47] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [30 56 14] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [34 63  3] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [17 40 43] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [56 36  8] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [52 45  3] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [35 34 31] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [25 41 34] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [ 1 78 21] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [ 1 49 50] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [51 31 18] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [50 10 40] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [36 63  1] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [30 30 40] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [27 30 43] sum of vector:  100
vec:  [21 27 52] sum of vector:  100
```

*There is a need to check that indeed the resulted vector sum to the desired value, because this isn't guaranteed*

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer to the comment below from the OP:

I am not sure how much randomness you get like this, but:

```
def three_to_100_b():
    a3 = random.randint(0,1)
    a2 = random.randint(0,50)
    a1 = 100-a3-a2
    return a1, a2, a3
```

will give you three **pseudo**-random numbers, the first in the range 0-100, the second in the range 0-50, the last one 0 or 1, and summing 100.

But notice that the randomness between `a1` and `a2` is really small --- they are on a straight line +0 or -1 by definition...

[image]

#### Notice, new answer --- the old one has flaws in randomness.

One method to have three numbers that sum up to 100 is to generate three random numbers, and then scale them so that their sums is 100. This is overly verbose, but the idea is:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import random

def three_to_100():
    r1 = random.randint(0,100)
    r2 = random.randint(0,100)
    r3 = random.randint(0,100)
    a1 = r1*100/(r1+r2+r3)
    a2 = r2*100/(r1+r2+r3)
    a3 = 100 - a1 - a2
    return a1, a2,a3

#main
print("x\t y\t z")
for i in range(1000):
    # print(three_to_100())
    a=three_to_100()
    print("{}\t  {}\t {}".format(*a))
```

I plotted the (x,y) pairs for the first 1000 numbers (the third number is represented by the color of the dot) and I have:

[image: Output of the x,y,z tuples]

### old answer

You can generate a number from 0 to 100, then another one from 0 to (100 - the first number), and so on. The last one won't be random:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import random

def three_to_100():
    r1 = random.randint(0,100)
    r2 = random.randint(0,100-r1)
    r3 = 100 - r1 - r2
    return r1, r2,r3

#main
for i in range(10):
    print(three_to_100())
```

The output will be:

```sh
[romano:~/tmp] % ./randsum.py 
(26, 7, 67)
(85, 13, 2)
(43, 41, 16)
(75, 22, 3)
(66, 19, 15)
(30, 16, 54)
(43, 30, 27)
(36, 2, 62)
(31, 2, 67)
(91, 0, 9)
```

This is a plot of the first two numbers — they seem pretty random, but maybe it's true that they seem a bit crowded on the x-y axis.

[image: distribution of 1000 numbers]

Comment: I think that this solution is valid, but it is not completely random

Comment: @DavidS I am not an expert in statistics, but of course, if three numbers sum up 100 one of them is not random at all... Anyway, I like your solution too.

Comment: your answer can be easily understand by me but my problem is for each value of array have to be randomize in specific range which is 1st array (0,100), 2nd (0,50), 3nd(0,1) and need to be equal to 100. are they any possible solution?

Comment: So you need three numbers, one in the range [0,100], the other in [0,50], and the other in [0,1] which must sum 100? Integer or float?

Comment: Tried a solution --- but notice that the randomness is very  small, basically you have just one random number and the other is more or less fixed (±1 depending on the value of the third number, 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer with numpy. It works without retry logic

```
def randint_sum_total(num_elem, min, max, total_limit):
    """It will create random numbers between min and max range but the sum will match the expected_total

    Args:
        num_elem (int): number of items
        min (int): minimum value
        max (int): max value
        total_limit (int): sum of all values should match this

    Returns:
        array: list contains random numbers
    """
    random_numbers = (np.random.uniform(min, max, num_elem)).astype(int)
    scaled_numbers = random_numbers / random_numbers.sum() * total_limit
    # Round the scaled numbers to integers
    rounded_numbers = np.round(scaled_numbers).astype(int)
    rounded_numbers[rounded_numbers<min] = min # if the scaled num less than min_range , add min_range
    rounded_numbers[rounded_numbers>max] = max # if the scaled num greater than max_range , add max_range
    remaining = total_limit - rounded_numbers.sum()
    indices = np.where((rounded_numbers + remaining > min) & (rounded_numbers + remaining < max))
    if len(indices[0]) > 0:  # Check if there are values in the range (min_range , max_range)
        # Add remaining to the first value meeting the condition
        rounded_numbers[indices[0][0]] += remaining

    return rounded_numbers
```